# How to use member type of a template class without specifying unnecessary template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am trying to use a member type of a template class, which does not depend on any template parameters of the template class. I would like to keep the type as the member type due to its logic, but I do not want to specify the unnecessary template parameters of the class whenever I want to use the member type outside the class.

Consider the following:

```
class Dummy { };

// Template class
template<typename T>
class A {
  public:

    template<typename T2>
    class MemberType : public T2 {
      public:
        T2 t2;
    };

};

int main()
{
  typename A<Dummy>::template MemberType<Dummy> m1; // okay
  typename A::template MemberType<Dummy> m2;        // not okay!

  return 0;
}
```

I got the following compiler error when I try to compile using g++:

```
error: ‘template<class T> class A’ used without template parameters
   typename A::template MemberType<Dummy> m2; // not okay!
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can't. Since you use a template you must specify the template argument otherwise compile doesn't know how to construct the class. Remember the template itself is not a class, the compiler build a class based on the template's arguments. Are you sure do you need the external template though? It's probably a design matter.

Comment: Not related, but you need neither `typename`, not `template` to refer to `MemberType` here.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use a member type of a template class, which does not
>   depend on any template parameters of the template class.

As a nested type within `class A<T>`, `MemberType` *does* depend on the template parameter `T`.

i.e. `A<T>::MemberType<T2>` and `A<U>::MemberType<T2>` are distinct classes.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible. A template is just a template. There is very little you can do with it before actually instantiating it for a concrete type. There could be a specialization for `A` that has no nested `MemberType` at all.

> I would like to keep the type as the member type due to its logic,
>   [...]

...but it seems the logic is something else: The `MemberType` does not depend on `A`, hence it should not be part of a template that depends on `A`.

Sloppy speaking `template<typename T>` can be read as "**everything** that follows depends on `T`". Even if you think it does not, there could always be a specialization that changes anything inside `A`. If you want `MemberType` to not depend on `T` then declare it outside `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in a [template](/questions/tagged/template) is dependent on the parameter(s) - meaning a [template-specialization](/questions/tagged/template-specialization) might not even have `class MemberType`.

But you can make a default parameter - you still need to write `<>` though (but you can omit `template` usually - even `typename`, but I left that):

```
class Dummy { };

// Template class
template <class T = void>
class A {
  public:

    template<typename T2>
    class MemberType : public T2 {
      public:
        T2 t2;
    };

};

int main()
{
  typename A<Dummy>::MemberType<Dummy> m1; // okay
  typename A<>::MemberType<Dummy> m2;        // also ok

  return 0;
}
```

As others have pointed out, this somewhat looks like an anti-pattern though - since the inner type is not dependent on the parameter of the outer template class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any workaround for this?

`MemberType` is a type dependent from a template parameter so, necessarily, you have to pass through the containing template a template parameter to define it

```
typename A<SomeType>::template MemberType<AnotherType> m2;
```

Taking in count that your not interested in external `SomeType` parameter, the best workaround I can imagine is the use of a `using` as follows (or something similar)

```
template <typename T>
using MemberType_t = typename A<T>::template MemberType<T>;
```

to reduce typewriting.

The following is a full compiling simplified example

```
#include <type_traits>

class Dummy { };

template <typename>
struct A
 {
   template <typename T2>
   struct MemberType : public T2
    { T2 t2; };
 };

template <typename T>
using MemberType_t = typename A<T>::template MemberType<T>;

int main ()
 {
   typename A<Dummy>::template MemberType<Dummy> m1;

   MemberType_t<Dummy> m2; // compile

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(m1), decltype(m2)>::value, "!" );
 }
```